# arango shell not included in ArangoDB 3.6.3 for macos

Tags: arangodb

I am a new ArangoDB user. I just installed ArangoDB 3.6.3 on mac. There's no arangosh in the install package. Where can I get a REPL shell? Manual is of no help, unfortunately.

Regards,
tiari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support tools are part of the "client" package, which is a separate download.  You can get it from their [download page](https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/macosx/), or use a [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/arangodb/arangodb).

Comment: Thanks! I focused on dmg part of the download only, missed that client part.

Comment: @tiari, I see that you're a new user, so I mention this as a training note, but when someone provides an acceptable answer to your question, don't forget to mark it as "accepted".  This helps future users more easily find the information they are looking for.  Thanks for asking, and good luck with your project!